# cannot connect to vnc after vncserver install and restart

Tags: vnc

I used the instructions on this site:

https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-vnc-server-on-ubuntu-14.04

to install VNC server on my Ubuntu 14.04.  It worked fine.  I could login using VNC Viewer 5.1.1 from Windows.  Today I did apt-get upgrade and restarted.  After restarting the machine, I could not login either using VNC (Connection Refused 10061) or on the console.  syslog showed a problem reading ~/.ICEauthority so I chowned that and now can login on the console but VNC still gives 'Connection refused.'

When I try to start vncviewer from a shell, I get:

Wrong type or access mode of /home/jjen009/.vnc.

jj

Comment: PS - when I try to start vncserver from a shell login, I get:Wrong type or access mode of /home/jjen009/.vnc.

Comment: So what are the type and access mode? Please add the output of `ls -ld ~/.vnc/` to your post (also can you clarify whether you are trying to start `vncviewer` as per your question or `vncserver` as indicated in your comment).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'type' and 'access mode.'

ls -ld ./.vnc:

drwxrwxr-x 2 jjen009 jjen009 4096 Jan 17 14:16 .vnc

I'm trying to start vncviewer from Windows to talk to the Ubuntu machine.  Worked until I rebooted.

jj

Comment: Have you verified (using `ps` - or `netstat`) that the VNC service actually started?

Comment: This blog describes how to set up rdp: http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=8952&cpage=4 . The key to getting it to work on Ubuntu 16 and above is to install an alternative desktop environment.

Answer (score 7):

There is a known bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vnc4/+bug/1200451
This means that even a super use can't start vnc if the relevant configuration files are owned by a regular user.
Check with ls -la . on the home directory e.g. in my case:

```
ls -la .
drwxr-xr-x  2 wf   users      4096 Nov 10 10:57 .vnc
```

when I went out of super use mode i could run:

```
vncserver
```

to get:

```
New 'X' desktop is capri:1

Starting applications specified in /home/wf/.vnc/xstartup
Log file is /home/wf/.vnc/capri:1.log
```