# vncserver won't run in a shell script executed with sudo

Tags: 16.04, command-line, bash, scripts, vnc

I have a shell script that installs several programs with sudo apt-get then opens vncserver, then installs more stuff.

This works:

```
#!/bin/sh
vncserver

>./my_script.sh
```

But this does not work:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo apt-get update
vncserver

>./my_script.sh
```

Nor does this work:

```
#!/bin/sh
vncserver

>sudo ./my_script.sh
```

When it doesn't work, it returns the error `vncserver: Wrong type or access mode of /home/username/.vnc`.

Someone on [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/574593/cannot-connect-to-vnc-after-vncserver-install-and-restart) question said that this was a known problem. So how can I run vncserver in my_script?

Comment: And if you do `sudo <the-script>` does it work?

Comment: If it's a sudo session it doesn't work, even if the sudo is called inside the script. sudo <the-script> would be like in my 3rd example and it gives the error I mentioned. Is there a way to exit out of a sudo session, run vncserver, then go back into sudo, all inside of the shell script?

Comment: What is the `>` you have there? Is that actually part of your script? `>./my_script.sh` will just empty the file `./my_script.sh`. What is the username in the error message? Is that your username or root's?

Comment: Sorry, thats my way of writing the final command you write into terminal after writing your shell script.

Comment: it's roots username. It's a cloud instance so i think there's only 1 account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sudo -u` to revert to the non-root user for a particular command.

Ex.:

```
$ cat myscript.sh
#!/bin/sh

whoami

sudo -u $SUDO_USER whoami
```

then

```
$ sudo ./myscript.sh
[sudo] password for steeldriver: 
root
steeldriver
```